# Suddenly unable to load or open Ubuntu OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have been working with Ubuntu 16 LTS (dual OS along with Windows 10) since past 3-4 years. But for the past 1 year I haven't used it. Now when I tried to open/load it I am not able to load it. Even when I hit F9 to open boot manager, it still shows option for Ubuntu but when I select it, only Windows 10 is loading. But in the disk management, it still shows the allocated storage space for Ubuntu. Help me to resolve this asap without loss of data.[image]
NOTE: I have some files and Python packages installed in Ubuntu, so I need a solution that doesn't hamper these things.

Comment: Insufficient information to diagnose the problem. "It does not boot" could have a dozen possible causes. One solution: Boot from a LiveUSB, mount the Ubuntu partition, back up your data to some other media, then re-install,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the below options can solve your problem:

1. Try to disable **Secure Boot**.
2. Boot from any Ubuntu live USB and try to repair Grub Boot Loader

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
   ```

   where XXX is the device of your installed Ubuntu